# Action Mailer not executing Proc to generate TO field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, proc, rails-activejob

**UP** 04/08/2015 : Is it actually possible to use both `.deliver_later` and a proc ?

**My problem :**

My email doesn't execute the procedure to generate the TO field, thus sending a bad email on postfix

Postfix log

```
sudo tail -n 150 /var/log/mail.log

Jul 30 17:39:44 je postfix/pickup[3974]: 0DA531FC2AFA: uid=1030 from=<candidature@myorg.com>
Jul 30 17:39:44 je postfix/cleanup[8430]: 0DA531FC2AFA: message-id=<55ba453fc4fd1_20e02375a9c04882a@myorg.mail>
Jul 30 17:39:44 je postfix/qmgr[3506]: 0DA531FC2AFA: from=<candidature@telecom-etude.com>, size=18915, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jul 30 17:39:44 je postfix/error[8522]: 0DA531FC2AFA: to=<Proc:0xbbd2989c@/var/www/intranet_rails_production/releases/20150729170507/app/mailers/mailing_lists_mailer.rb:42>, relay=none, delay=0.41, delays=0.22/0.02/0/0.17, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
Jul 30 17:39:44 je postfix/error[8522]: 0DA531FC2AFA: to=<#<Proc:0xbbd2989c@/var/www/intranet_rails_production/releases/20150729170507/app/mailers/mailing_lists_mailer.rb:42>>, relay=none, delay=0.52, delays=0.22/0.02/0/0.28, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
```

Controller

```
...
if Rails.env.production? # Using :sendmail as delivery method
  MailingListsMailer.action(@mail).deliver_later
else # Typically using :letter_opener or :file as delivery method
  MailingListsMailer.action(@mail).deliver_now
...
```

Mailer

```
class MailingListsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def action(message)
    format_mail_params(message)
    mail(
      to: Proc.new {read_emails_file},
      ...
    )
   end

    private

    def read_emails_file
      File.read('emails.txt').split('\n')
    end
end
```

Config

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "localhost",
    :domain => "myorg.fr"
  }
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myorg.fr', protocol: 'https' }
```

EDIT : I was using a proc as suggested in the [ActionMailer Basics #2.3.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the Proc wrapper at all, try this:

```
def action(message)
    format_mail_params(message)
    mail(
        to: read_emails_file,
        ...
    )
end
```

To debug it, do something like this:

```
def action(message)
    format_mail_params(message)

    puts "*"*50
    emails = read_emails_file
    puts emails
    puts "*"*50

    mail(
        to: emails,
        ...
    )
end
```

Then check the server logs for the message that looks something like:

```
*******************************************************************
[...]
*******************************************************************
```

**Iterate the Emails**

Because you don't want to divulge everyone's email, and avoid spam detection, you may want to iterate the emails array:

```
def action(message)
  format_mail_params(message)

  read_emails_file.each do |email|
    mail(
        to: email,
        ...
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm yeah I remembered reading some doc mentionning Proc could be used and I thought maybe it was relevant... I have 500+ emails in that file so it's not that big. Also something I never understood...are the names all gonna appear in the TO field for every recipient ? If possible I'd like to avoid to divulge 499 emails to every recipient ^^"

Comment: In this methodology, yes, the names would all end up in the To field.  This could also cause problems with spam detection.  You may want to iterate the emails.  I've updated my answer to include that approach.  If this works out, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. 1. How are the messages delivered ? I thought ActionMailer was supposed to return a mail object on which I could call `deliver_later/now` in the controller. Shall I return an array of emails and deliver every one of them ?
2. I was also wondering, what are the PROs/CONs of putting all the emails in the bcc field instead of your approach ?

Comment: You should be able to just add the method call to the end of the mail call: mail(...).deliver_later

Comment: As for using BCC, not totally sure.  My guess is possible spam detection, however, I'm not fully up to speed on those topics.

Comment: Sure, I won't be able to test it right now, but I'll definitely come back to accept the answer. I swear it on my 1.9k reputation :D . ALso I'll probably try the BCC solution first, otherwise I'd also need to add extra code to deliver the mails [See this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325502/loop-working-but-mailer-not)

Comment: Did you get a chance to test that out?

Comment: Not really in live production, however in my test environment it seems to populate the bcc field correctly so I believe it's ok. To be honest, we used the iteration method on our old platform (running Play!) but I didn't quite like it, which is why I prefer to use a single email with bcc field.